# Help with making first script

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control, greasemonkey

I need help with programming a script for GreaseMonkey.
All I want it to do is press "CTRL" and "TAB" and then enter a URL into the address bar. Then repeat.

How can I do this? Where do I start?
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can actually send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to the browser and have it interpreted as a "switch tabs command".  That would be a security hole if you could.

But if you want to open a new tab, you can do that easily.  Here's a starter script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Tab Opener
// @namespace       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321507/
// @include         http://stackoverflow.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

GM_openInTab ("http://www.google.com/");
```